# Haskell append to a list conditionally

Tags: list, haskell, concatenation

I have 2 lists which I am trying to fill will items. While reading from stdin, depending on the value of one of the things read, I want to append to a different list. Example,

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)

main = do
    n <- getLine
    let l1 = [], l2 = []
        in replicateM (read n) (getLine >>= (\line ->
            case line of "Yes" ->
                -- do something with line
                -- and append value of that thing to l1
                          "No" ->
                -- do something else
                -- append this value to l2
            putStrLn line))
```

I realise the above code has syntax errors and such, but hopefully you can see what I am trying to and suggest something.

This is the answer I came up with

While we are at it, can someone explain why this gives me an infinite list:

```
let g = []
let g = 1:g
-- g now contains an infinite list of 1's
```

---

This is what I finally came up with:

```
import Control.Monad(replicateM)
import Data.Either

getEither::[String] -> [Either Double Double]
getEither [] = []
getEither (line:rest) = let [n, h] = words line
                            fn = read f :: Double
                            e = case heist of "Yes" -> Left fn
                                              "No"  -> Right fn
                            in e : getEither rest

main = do
    n <- getLine
    lines <- replicateM (read n) getLine
    let tup = partitionEithers $ getEither lines :: ([Double], [Double])
    print tup
```

Not sure how `fmap` could have been used in this instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short ghci session that may give you some ideas:

```
> :m + Control.Monad Data.Either
> partitionEithers <$> replicateM 3 readLn :: IO ([Int], [Bool])
Left 5
Right True
Left 7
([5,7],[True])
```

The answer to your second question is that let is recursive; so the two `g`s in `let g = 1:g` are referring to the same in-memory object.

Comment: What is that `<$>` symbol?

Comment: @Smac89 It's operator symbol for `fmap`

Comment: @Smac89 `(<$>)` can be spelled many other ways, one of which may be familiar to you: `fmap`, `liftA`, `liftM`. You may also think of it as `\f ma -> do { a <- ma; return (f a) }`, though it is slightly more general than that.

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking in term of mutable variables: you are "initializing" `l1,l2` to the empty list and then reasoning about updating them with longer lists. This design works fine in imperative programming, but not so simply in pure functional programming since it involves mutation.

Now, even in pure functional programming we have ways to simulate mutation, through monads. For instance, once can achieve mutation here through `IORefs` or `StateT IO`. In this case, though, is would be an unnecessarily complex way to solve the task.

You want to append data to form two lists. You want to use `replicateM`, which is fine. The point is that `replicateM` will build just one list, instead of two. The question now is: how can we create a list which is easily split into two?

A first ugly attempt is to generate a list of tagged values, i.e. a list of pairs:

```
case line of
   "Yes" -> let value = ... in
            return ("for l1", value)
   "No"  -> let value = ... in
            return ("for l2", value)
```

Doing this would make `replicateM` produce a list such as

```
[("for l1", value1), ("for l1", value2), ("for l2", value3), ...]
```

which we can then split into two lists.

The use of strings for tags looks however a bit unelegant, since a boolean would suffice:

```
case line of
   "Yes" -> let value = ... in
            return (True, value)
   "No"  -> let value = ... in
            return (False, value)
```

An even better approach would be to use the `Either a b` type:

```
case line of
   "Yes" -> let value1 = ... in
            return (Left value1)
   "No"  -> let value2 = ... in
            return (Right value2)
```

The nice consequence of the above is that `value1` and `value2` can even be of different types. The previous snippets forced them to share their type: since we build a list of pairs each pair must have the same type. The new list is now instead of type `[Either a b]` where `a` is the type of values to be put in `l1`, and `b` that for `l2`.

Once you get a `[Either a b]` you want to split it in `[a]` and `[b]`. As @DanielWagner suggests in his answer, you can exploit `partitionEithers` for this.